# Login Procedure that does not require a Email Address

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, asp.net-membership

I have been asked to create a site where the user isn't required to provide a email to login because of privacy issues. In the past I have simple said this isn't advisable but in this case the client has stringently requested it. My initial thoughts are to potentially create administrators with a email whom could create generic logins (username and a password) and pass them to members of there group on site. Then at least I have a point of contact for login resets and such.

Has anyone had any experience with such situations where they have needed to create logins without the use of a email address? Could you direct me towards any relevant materials or tutorials that may be of use. I'm using MVC3 to develop this project.

Comment: The issue here is surely requirements - not technical. Without an email, how will users who misplace their passwords obtain a new one?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what the problem is. A login screen usually takes a username/password. A signup screen could take an email but what's the problem with not including it, other than of course angry users who forgot their password and who cannot obtain a new one. But that's not a technical problem. It's a functional.

Comment: Yes sorry question should have been phrased in two parts. How to create the customer membership and the second part was functional but I was looking for potential ideas of how anyone else has dealt with such things as password resets without having a email registered to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand your question right and you want to implement a login using username and password instead of email adress and password.
In that case you would have to implement your own custom membership provider and a custom roleprovider if needed.

You want to check the following page for more information:

[Custom Membership Provider @ Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/WSSecurityProvider.aspx)

EDIT
Fyi you dont need to implement every function - just implement the ones you need.
Custom membership provider from some of my older mvc3 projects. Removed most of the not-implemented functions for shorter code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace Domain.Models
{
    public class PlatformMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
    {
        public SalesModelContainer ******** = new SalesModelContainer();

        public override bool ChangePassword(string username, string oldPassword, string newPassword)
        {
            var user = ********.UserSet.Single(s => s.Email == username);
            if (user.Password == oldPassword)
            {
                user.Password = newPassword;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public override string GetUserNameByEmail(string email)
        {
            var user = ********.UserSet.Single(s => s.Email == email);
            return user.CompanyName;
        }

        public override void UpdateUser(System.Web.Security.MembershipUser user)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        //TODO: use MD5 for password encryption
        public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
        {
            bool returnValue;
            var user = ********.UserSet.SingleOrDefault(s => (s.Email == username) && (s.Password == password));
            if (user != null)
                returnValue = true;
            else
                returnValue = false;

            return returnValue; 
        }


    }
}
```